# SAS macro to append datasets based on dataset name in work library

Tags: sas

I want to write a macro that will automatically identify datasets in my work library with names as PCT_202007, PCT_202008 and append them to final work table. How can I do this?

Comment: Why don't you share what you have tried so far, then people may be more disposed to help you?

Comment: I tried this
DATA FINAL;
%DO i =1 %TO 2;
SET PCT_&MONTHID_&I;
END;
;
RUN;

Comment: You can use a list as well. `set pct_202007 - pct_202008;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need for a macro. Use the colon operator like this:

```
data pct_202007; set sashelp.class; run;
data pct_202008; set sashelp.class; run;
data pct_202009; set sashelp.class; run;

data want;
   set work.pct_:;
run;
```

Comment: You might want to also store the origination of the data rows. If so, use the `SET WORK.PCT_: INDSNAME=_dataset_; source=_dataset_;`